# Angular bootstrap datetime picker

Tags: angular-ui-bootstrap, angular-ui, angular-bootstrap

Though there are various good datetime pickers available, I'm looking for a single component which has all these following features -

1. Date and time selection in one go
2. Only date selection
3. Only time selection
4. Multiple dates selection (Not to be misunderstood with date range selection)

I'm unable to find a component which has all the above. The reason behind I'm looking for a single component instead of using multiple components is consistent UX and optimum performance.

Answer (score 1):

Here's one built off of ngBootstrap. The ngBootstrapCalendar control supports multiple date selections.
https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-datetimepicker

Comment: this datetimepicker is not compatible with higher version of `angular` and `ng-bootstrap`. It has many errors in it.

Comment: @FahadSubzwari I updated it to the latest version of angular and ng-bootstrap. Take another look.

Comment: @Cirem, If backdate is selected datepicker popup current date calendar opens and today's date is also not highlighted